# EOG (Image Viewer) broke after upgrading to 19.04

Tags: upgrade, python, eog

I just upgraded to 19.04 and now EOG won't work, either from Nautilus or the command line. When I open it via the command line, I get

```
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 603, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 589, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 321, in addusersitepackages
    addsitedir(user_site, known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 213, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 165, in addpackage
    f = open(fullname, "r")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/_bootlocale.py", line 35, in getpreferredencoding
    if sys.flags.utf8_mode:
AttributeError: 'sys.flags' object has no attribute 'utf8_mode'
```

So, I'm assuming a python error, however:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.flags.utf8_mode
0
```

One thing that I noticed is that `python` now points to `python2` instead of `python3` (as it had when I was running 18.10). I thought this might be the source of the problem, as in python2.7, `sys.flags` does not have a `utf8_mode`.

I changed `/usr/bin/python` to point towards `python3` instead, but it didn't work; I got the same error as above when I attempted to start `eog`.

Does anybody have any idea what's going on here?